# Combinatorics - Trying to understand how to calculate the probability ( random variable )

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

The Question:
In a course of probability, 153 people study.
All student has birthday and the date distributely uniform for 365 days.
All birthdays are independent.
While the semester is going there are 11 lectures.
If a lecture has birthday ( atleast one ), the committee gives a cake.
X is the number of cakes that was given by the committee while the semester.
What is E[X].

My problem:
I have the answer, the only thing that bothers me and I can not understand, how to calculate the probability that $P(X_i=0)$, which means the probability that in lecture $i$ there is not any birthday ( or same goes for $P(X_i=1)$, to yes have birthday ), I have the solution, they said:
$P(X_i=0) = \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{153}$, and thus $P(X_i=1)$ I can reach it.
But my problem is understanding, why $P(X_i=0)$ is that number? Basically I am asking for a way to understand it. The reason behind it, the logic.
And is there any easy way to caulcate $P(X_i=1)$ without using $1-P(X_i=0)$?

Comment: For $P(X_i = 0)$ consider the cases you are looking at. You consider the cases where for a specific day it's no students birthday. For one student not to have birthday on that day the probability is $\frac{364}{365}$ since there are $365$ possible days and $364$ are desirable for this probability. Since they are independent we get your solution (we have to multiply the probabilities)

Comment: Okay, I understand most of it actually, the only thing that bothers me, $\frac {364} {365}$, why is it the probability? sorry for being "stupid", I am really bad at combinatorics

Comment: For $P(X_i = 1)$ you could also calculate the probabilities, you could look at the case where 'student a' has birthday on that lecture. So $(\frac{364}{365})^152 \cdot \frac{1}{365}$ and since there are 153 students in the class, you'd sum up the probabilites and get $\binom{153}{1} \cdot (\frac{364}{365})^152 \cdot \frac{1}{365}$

Comment: Oh the second one I understand the logic you did..,,,,,, regarding the $P(X_i=0$, it is $\frac {364} {365}$ because a birthday is once in a year, so you can have birthday in $\frac 1 {365}$?

Comment: that's what I explained in my first comment. There are 365 possible days for a student to have her birthday. Since one of them is the day of lecture $i$, 364 of them are desirable in the sense, that it's not the day of the lecture. So just looking at it as an evenly distributed probability

Comment: I don't know on which theoretical basis you are trying to solve this problem but maybe you should look at your definitions of probability spaces again in order to understand my argument. I am afraid without the theoretical foundation I won't be able to explain it any further

Comment: Oh, I had problem because there was two stuff, either the lecture and the birthday, so I thought in order to have a specific probability for the birthday, I had to count somehow the lecturers, did not understand before that I can just leave the lectures to understand the birthday single handedly. Thanks! I understand now!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why $P(X_i=0)= \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{153}\;\;$ ?
P(a student  doesn't have birthday on day $i)  
= \frac{364}{365}$
By the multiplication rule,
P($153$ students don't have a birthday on day i)
$= P(X_i=0) = \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{153}$

And P(at least 1 student has a birthday on day i)
$= P(X_i=1)= 1 - P(X_i=0)$
This *is* the easiest way to compute $P(X_i=1)$

We can then use linearity of expectation to determine $E[X]$, the number of cakes to be ordered.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, Raoul helped already, but since there is an answer here, and the answer is explained well, I will make it the answer for future people to see if they need help at something of the sort.
Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome !

Comment: Asking before summarizing someone else's comments in an answer is always an option

Comment: @RaoulLuqué: When you are typing out an answer, you can't simultaneously see what other comments/answers are being put up.

Comment: @trueblueanil That's actually [not correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142584/when-writing-an-answer-notify-that-comments-have-been-posted-or-edits-have-been)

Comment: @RaoulLuqué: **1** My friend, I hardly needed help answering this question, having previously answered some $50$ questions on expectation/indicator variables. **2** If it is points you are concerned with, pl. post your comments as an answer and ping me, I'll request OP to untick my answer and tick yours.